# how can i send input int to another file in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

i want to send input int to function in another file but i found error

this is home.py

```
a=Entry(win, width=21)
a.place(x=200, y=155)
b=Entry(win, width=22)
b.place(x=375, y=155)
```

this is function.py

```
t1=int(a.get())
t2=int(b.get())
t3=(1/3)*pi*t1*t1*t2
```

but after I run it i found erorr

```
t1=int(a.get())
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: How do you run the two files? It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

NameError: name 'a' is not defined is causing because 'a' is not declared in function.py

you have to `import` another script in the working script if you want to use any variable/function that exists in another script.

**example**:
If, `home.py` contains `a`

```py
b = 2
c = 3
a = b + c
```

and you want to use it inside `function.py`, then in function.py the code will be as follows:

```py
import home
x = home.a
mult = x*x
print(mult)
```

This will output `25`